# 'Whenever' equivalent for PHP or Symfony2 for dealing with cronjobs?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, cron-task

Is there a bundle or something for dealing with cronjobs?

I miss Ruby's [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever#readme), so I'm looking for something similar to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BCCCronManager](http://knpbundles.com/michelsalib/BCCCronManagerBundle)provides a web interface for managing cron table. It's the only maintained Symfony2 bundle about CRONs.

In plain PHP, you may be interested in [cron-expression](https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression) or [Crontab](https://github.com/yzalis/Crontab).

Answer (score 1):

You need Jobby

[Manage all your cron jobs without modifying crontab. Handles locking, logging, error emails, and more.](https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby)

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be the best option for PHP in 2017.